# Twig: How to display html content in the block title

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

In my symfony2 project, I have some twig temlates.
In one of them, I have the block title.

```
{% block title %}{{ announcement.title }}{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that the variable `{{ announcement.title }}` can be: `<em>test</em>`

In this case, my title will be `<em>test</em>` and it needs to be

> *test*

I have tryied the `{% block title %}{{ announcement.title|raw }}{% endblock %}` but nothing changed. This is only in the block title, if I put the raw filter in my block content, then it is fine.

Any idea on how to do that ?

EDIT:

Here is an example:

```
{% block title %}{{ announcement.title|raw }}{% endblock %}
{% block body_announcements %}{{ announcement.title|raw }}{% endblock %}
```

In the block title, I see `<em>test<em>` and in the block body_announcements I see *test* which is right.

Comment: You said _it needs to be test (in italic)_, and the solution has been given. You want to remove the tags?

Comment: right, I need the test to be in italic, but by using the proposed solutions, I still have the em tags there. This only in the title block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the [`raw` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) to display text and tags *as is*:

```
{% block title %}{{ announcement.title|raw }}{% endblock %}
```

Edit: The [`striptags` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/striptags.html) is used to display text without the tags:

```
{% block title %}{{ announcement.title|striptags }}{% endblock %}
```

## Example

### Twig code

```
{% set str = '<em>test</em>' %}
1: {{ str }}
2: {{ str|raw }}
3: {{ str|striptags }}
```

### Result

> 1: <em>test</em>

The `<em></em>` tag is escaped.

> 2: *test*

The `<em></em>` tag is displayed and interpreted by the browser.

> 3: test

The `<em></em>` tag is removed, only the text is shown.

Comment: Please show the entire code, I don't understand your problem with 2 blocks: how are they different?

Comment: There is an example in my question.

Comment: This can be a sloution that suits my needs, but why the raw does not work in the title block ??? !!!

Comment: I saw you updated your question, I don't see any reason with it behaves this way, sorry.

Comment: Strange. Could you please make your edit with striptags and I will accept this hack solution.

Comment: Okay, but your problem is not fixed, right? Maybe copy-pasting the entire twig file in your question may help.

Comment: I think I know why, apparently, the `<html>
<head>
<title>test</title></head></html>` can not hold html tags, so the solution is to strip them

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to escape `HTML` :

```
{% block title %}{{ announcement.title|e('html') }}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: That's the default behaviour: `{% set str = '<em>test</em>' %} {{ str|e('html') }} {{ str }}` display `<em>test</em> <em>test</em>`. Auto-escaping is enable by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try following...

```
{% block title %}{{ announcement.title|raw }}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I am afraid that this did not help, I have still the em tags that are displayed...

Comment: As described, the problem is that in the html title tag, there is no possibility to display html tags.